# Error closing token address with the CLI

Tags: spl-token, cli, solana-cli

Why do I get an error when I try to close a token address? ***spl-token close (token address)***

***Error: Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey= (my Ledger address)***

This is the same Ledger address I used to create the token.

I have used ***spl-token --accounts -v*** to verify that I have the correct token address and that all the tokens are burned.

So there are no tokens in the account address.

I use my Ledger with the CLI, and I do not get any verification on my Ledger when I use the ***spl-token close (token address)*** command.

Everything else works fine, I can create tokens, I can burn tokens, etc. then I get promoted on my Ledger to sign the transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Great question.

Please note that `spl-token close` expects a *different* address on the command line than `spl-token burn`.

For `spl-token burn`, you specify the token **account** address, i.e. the associated token account address for your wallet.

However, `spl-token close` is asking for the **token** address, not the token **account** address. The token address is another name for the token mint here, sometimes also called token mint address.

When you do your `spl-token accounts -v`, you will see the token address(es) in the left hand side, and the token **account** addresses on the right hand side.

Use the values on the left for `spl-token close`, but the values on the right for `spl-token burn`.

Don't ask me *why* the Solana folks did it that way, though. I think that will remain their little dark secret forever... :-)

Comment: I know that... I have done what you describe... I use the left value... as you can see above I use the spl-token close (token address)
I don't use spl-token close (account address)

That's why it's strange I get this: Error: Account could not be parsed as token account: pubkey= (my Ledger address)

Comment: Please post screenshots (black out keys if need to - but's just public keys anyway)